# Android: Open Spinner from Button

Tags: android, button, spinner

In an Android application, is it possible to open the spinner popup from a button click instead of pressing the actual spinner?

I have tried the following:

```
Button btnChange = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
            btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                     Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSpinner);
                     mySpinner.showContextMenu();
                  }
                });
```

Answer (score 59):

Sorry for late answer - it's possible:

```
((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner)).performClick();
```

Comment: @Zeratul, performClick directly calls the spinner's onItemSelected method, right? Is there any way we can show the spinner on another view's onClick & onItemSelected will be called after we select an item?

Answer (score 14):

It is possible, you just call it popup menu, not spinner.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            PopupMenu pum = new PopupMenu(this, findViewById(R.id.image));
            pum.inflate(R.menu.image_chooser_popup);
            pum.show();

          });
}
```

Your spinner (or popup) items goes to R.menu.image_chooser_popup:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:title="take a picture"
    android:titleCondensed="camera"
    android:visible="true"
    android:onClick="cameraIntent" />
<item
    android:title="choose picture from gallery"
    android:titleCondensed="string"
    android:visible="true"
    android:onClick="galleryIntent"/>
```

Hope this one helps some one. If you have any issues with my responce, please fill free to ask.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sSpinner);
Button btnChange = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnChange);    
btnChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mySpinner.performClick();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText packageName,partnerId,userName,mobileNo;
    Spinner dropDownMenu;
    ImageView dropDownImg;
    String[] loginType = {"Select","STAGE","PRODUCTION"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();

    }

    private void initViews(){
        packageName = findViewById(R.id.packageName);
        partnerId = findViewById(R.id.partnerId);
        userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mobileNo = findViewById(R.id.mobileNo);
        dropDownMenu = findViewById(R.id.dropdown_spinner);
        dropDownImg = findViewById(R.id.dropdown_img);
        ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,loginType);
        dropDownMenu.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        dropDownMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(dropDownOnClick());
        dropDownImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("schjsjcgg");
                dropDownMenu.performClick();
            }
        });
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener dropDownOnClick(){
       return new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               if (adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).equals("Select")){
                   String item1 = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                   System.out.println("Item1 = "+item1);

               }else{
                   String item2 = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                   System.out.println("Item2 = "+item2);

               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

           }
       };
    }
}
```