# How to show a popup of a spinner when clicking on a button?

Tags: android, button, android-spinner

There is a button and a spinner on a form; when the spinner is clicked it display a popup. I want to display the popup even when the button is clicked: how can it be done?

Comment: you need to call popup code on click of button.put your code script above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Open Spinner from Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838992/android-open-spinner-from-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `performClick()` on the Spinner, which has the same effect as actually clicking on the Spinner.

Unfortunately there is no more explicit way to programmatically open a Spinner's popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:prompt="@string/receive_coin_prompt"
   android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

Using **spinnerMode="dialog"** we can able to show dialog with spinner.